# Alice and Bob coin game

Tags: probability, contest-math

Assume fair coin.

Alice is the first player. She keeps tossing the coin until she gets the first Tails (T).

If Alice gets $k$ consecutive Heads (H), Bob has to keep tossing until he gets $k$ consecutive H.

What is the expected number of trials for Alice and Bob combined?

What I got so far:

Probability for Alice to get $k$ consecutive H = $P(k)$ = $1/2^{k+1}$.

Expected number of trials for Bob when Alice gets $k$ consecutive heads = $E_k$ = $2^{k+1}-2$.

So the expected number of trials for Alice and Bob combined:

E = $\sum_{k=0}^{\inf} P(k) (k+1+E_k)$

= $\sum_{k=0}^{\inf} (1 + k/2^{k+1} - 1/2^{k+1})$

But this diverges.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What exactly did you read or hear that makes you think the expectation is finite?

Comment: I cannot say for certain that the expectation is finite. The source: http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/01-random.pdf  - Problem 1

Comment: I guess it comes down to whether that author would accept "no finite expectation" as an "exact" answer.